# Noah’s Ark themed manga that I forgot the name of

Tags: story-identification, manga

This manga has been haunting me for years. The main key details that I remember is that the mc suddenly gets a power to warp people after getting a dream from God, and shoots around while portraying his tainted mentality to the readers.

I remember a scene where he’s in a bus and starts shooting everyone so they all get outside and panic before he gets teleported. Other key detail was about how it was a Noah’s Ark manga where the God asked everyone for their “ideals” or reason for living, and then they would be allowed on the boat. MC gets in, his girl doesn’t, so he gets off and has sex with her as the boat takes off in the sky, with whirlpools and storms happening on the earth as it gets destroyed with them on it.

Although I remember it so vividly, whenever I try searching up “finger shooting” [*Inuyashiki*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inuyashiki) just shows up, and if I search “*Noah’s ark*” nothing similar shows.

Comment: Was the Noah's ark theme a major element or just something that happened in a wider story?

Comment: When you say the MC was shooting people, do you mean he was firing bullets at people with a gun? I ask, because you used the phrase "finger shooting" later in the question, which makes it sound like he was firing something with just his fingers. Also, what do you mean by the MC having a "tainted mentality"? And _why_ was he shooting people? Was he just a maniac or something?

Comment: [You can't solve every problem with finger guns...](https://media.giphy.com/media/W9d37aHZgWyuMCGAsU/giphy-downsized-large.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [*'Shuumatsu no Tenki'* (AKA '*A Catastrophe Report*')](https://myanimelist.net/manga/91601/Shuumatsu_no_Tenki)?

> "There are too many unnecessary people"—A story of destruction
> dedicated to a certain person who thought such.
>
> 25-year-old, no money, no job, no girlfriend. Kurokawa, a man absorbed
> with an anime called "Meromero Melodies" and on the fast track to
> nowhere in life, grabs hold of a certain ability, "BANG."
>
> [image]

Gifted a power by god to sort people into necessary and unnecessary, Kurokawa can make people disappear by pointing at them. Suffice to say, things get progressively weirder after that.

[image]